# Add logged user as author of model, but keep ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, django-2.2

I want when add article, current logged user to be added as author, I'm also using ForegnKey to user and want to keep it, but right now throw error:

**objects/models.py:**

```
from django.db import models
from users.models import ProfileUser

    class Object(models.Model):
        author = models.ForeignKey(ProfileUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
        address = models.CharField(max_length=300)
        content = models.TextField()

        def __str__(self):
            return f"{self.title}"
```

**objects/forms.py:**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Object


class ObjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Object
        fields = [
            'title',
            'address',
            'content',
        ]
```

**objects/views.py:**

```
def add_object(request):
    form = ObjectForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.author = request.user
        obj.save()
        return redirect('home')

    context = {
        'form': form
    }

    return render(request, "add_object.html", context)
```

Also I rewrite default django user model:

**users/models.py:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

# Create your models here.


class ProfileUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile_image = models.URLField()

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User) # Still don't know how, but next rows create ProfileUser when User is created
    def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            ProfileUser.objects.create(user=instance)

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        instance.profileuser.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user}"
```

Error:

```
Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x04CD3B30>>": "Object.author" must be a "ProfileUser" instance.
```

Comment: try using `@login_required` above `def add_object(request):`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author must be a `ProfileUser` instance as the error message says, because you declared the author field (of the `Object` model) as a `ProfileUser`.

In `add_object` method, `obj.author` needs to be a `ProfileUser` instance, therefore you should get that instance by looking up the user.

```
def add_object(request):
    form = ObjectForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.author = ProfileUser.objects.get(user=request.user)
        obj.save()
        return redirect('home')

    context = {
        'form': form
    }

    return render(request, "add_object.html", context)
```

If the current user doesn't always exist for the `ProfileUser` instance, you could use the `get_or_create` method for the author. Read more about that [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create)